# how do I install emacs packages from the command line?

Tags: package-repositories, command-line-arguments

I'm attempting to automate deployment of my different machines by scripting installation of emacs and emacs packages. While I realize that I can set up my `.emacs` file to automatically install packages if they're not found, I'd rather have these packages pre-installed.

I'm executing elisp from the command line like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/emacs --batch --eval "(progn (package-initialize) (package-refresh-contents) (mapc 'package-install '(powerline airline-themes doom-themes sr-speedbar)))"
```

If all of the packages are currently installed, it works fine:

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
‘powerline’ is already installed
‘airline-themes’ is already installed
‘doom-themes’ is already installed
‘sr-speedbar’ is already installed
```

But, if one of the packages is not installed, it can't install the package and ends up saying it can't find a version of the package with a `-` appended to it (i.e. `sr-speedbar` becomes `sr-speedbar-`):

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
‘powerline’ is already installed
‘airline-themes’ is already installed
‘doom-themes’ is already installed
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
Package ‘sr-speedbar-’ is unavailable
```

When I paste the code into an Emacs minibuffer with `M-:`, it executes just fine.

**How can I properly install a package from MELPA (or other repository) from the command line without an interactive session?**

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, and it might make sense to have a look at the guix package manager. I believe it would suits your needs.